# IE7-8 on windows 7 - strange request formats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-7, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

does anyone know what is up with the request formats from IE running under windows 7?

i'm running a rails app that is checking on request.format.  when going to something like http://localhost where there is no format specified in the url, i'm seeing:

Firefox request.format is 'html'

IE7 and IE8 running under windows 7 professional request.format is 'application/x-ms-application'

IE7 and IE8 running under windows 7 ultimate request.format is 'jpg'

i can't make heads or tails of it. has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I've come across this issue as well. For some reason the format header isn't being set by IE, in a lot of cases its simply '*/*' (xp, vista) etc.